# Do while loop in class c++

Tags: c++, function, loops, class, while-loop

I am having a problem,more of a personal confusion,with a part of my code.You see the point is after asking the question about name amount weight given by n by user it should ask "add more?" and if replied Y or y it should either ask again for how many products do you want or just add 1 more.

```
class Class
{
public:
    char ask;
    vector <string> names;
    vector <int> amounts;
    vector <float> weights;
    string name;
    int amount, n;
    float weight;
    void market()
    {
        cout << "Give the number of products you want to get at Market : " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }

void get()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                cout << "Give product name,amount and weight : " << endl;
                cin >> name >> amount >> weight;
                cout << endl;
                names.push_back(name);
                amounts.push_back(amount);
                weights.push_back(weight);
                }
                cout << "Add more? (Y/n): "; // add more? Go on if yes...
                cin >> ask;

            }while (ask == 'Y' || ask == 'y');

        }
};
```

It is all in a class that i later put in main,is there any way to make it work that way?

Comment: Try removing the `}` above the `cout`.  Looks like your curly braces are not lining up.

Comment: ... which is why you should indent your code properly.  Then, problems like this are much easier  to see.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some syntax(improper bracketing) error in your code, there's some logic error that I can see. This is probably how you are looking for your `get()` function to be :

```
void get()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Give product name,amount and weight : " << endl;
        cin >> name >> amount >> weight;
        cout << endl;
        names.push_back(name);
        amounts.push_back(amount);
        weights.push_back(weight);
    }
    cout << "Add more? (Y/n): "; // add more? Go on if yes...
    cin >> ask;
    while (ask == 'Y' || ask == 'y'){
        cout << "Give product name,amount and weight : " << endl;
        cin >> name >> amount >> weight;
        cout << endl;
        names.push_back(name);
        amounts.push_back(amount);
        weights.push_back(weight);
        cout << "Add more? (Y/n): "; // add more? Go on if yes...
        cin >> ask;
    }
}
```

The above code will first take **n** inputs from the user and then asks the user if wants to input more number of items. The `while()` loop will keep running until the user enters `Y` or `y` as the input.

Hope this solves your issue !